# Posting innerHtml of a dynamically generated div using c#

Tags: c#, html, innerhtml

`

```js
$("#btnAdd").click(function () {
                var $tr = $("<tr>");
                $tr.append("<td>Ravi</td><td>50</td><td>G@gmail.com</td><td>1000000</td>");
                $("#tbl tbody").append($tr);
                $("#txthidden").val($("#divTable").html());
                $("#txthidden").val().replace("<table>", "swe");
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divtbl" runat="server">
  <table id="tbl">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Mail</th>
        <th>Number</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Raj</td>
        <td>25</td>
        <td>Raj@gmail.com</td>
        <td>9999999</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Gopu</td>
        <td>29</td>
        <td>Goups@gmail.com</td>
        <td>9749612767</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  
  <input type="button" id="btnExport"  runat="server" value="Export"/>
  <input type="button" id="btnAdd"  runat="server" value="Add Row"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="txthidden" runat="server" />
```

`I have got a html table enclosed inside a div tag.I need to export the data to excel.For doing that I am posting the page, and on its post i have put some c# code for exporting the same.In Order to get the table data I have used the code

```
        Response.ContentType = "application/force-download";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;    filename=Print.xls");
        Response.Write("<html xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\">");
        Response.Write("<head>");
        Response.Write("<META http-equiv=\"Content-Type\"       content=\"text/html; charset=utf-     8\">");
        Response.Write("<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>");
        Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorkbook>");
        Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorksheets>");
        Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorksheet>");
        Response.Write("<x:Name>Report Data</x:Name>");
        Response.Write("<x:WorksheetOptions>");
        Response.Write("<x:Print>");
        Response.Write("<x:ValidPrinterInfo/>");
        Response.Write("</x:Print>");
        Response.Write("</x:WorksheetOptions>");
        Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorksheet>");
        Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorksheets>");
        Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorkbook>");
        Response.Write("</xml>");
        Response.Write("<![endif]--> ");
        StringWriter tw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);
        divTable.RenderControl(hw);
        Response.Write(tw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
```

This works fine.But if I add a row into the table using jquery the same will not be reflected in the server side during post back. I.I tried another way by storing the inner Html of the table to a hidden text box and posting the form.But that ends up showing a server error with message "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client ".

Is there any way to accomplish what Iam intending to do

```html
<div id="divtbl" runat="server">
  <table id="tbl">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Mail</th>
        <th>Number</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Raj</td>
        <td>25</td>
        <td>Raj@gmail.com</td>
        <td>9999999</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Gopu</td>
        <td>29</td>
        <td>Goups@gmail.com</td>
        <td>9749612767</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Please show us your JavaScript/jQuery code including the adding of the dynamic content and the post back code

Comment: Your hidden text box value is `<table....` ?

Comment: @nelek  Actually i needed the html of the table...

Comment: When You put char `<` in server side text box, and it is in Your case because `runat=server` it will be `A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client `

Comment: Is there something I could do

Comment: Well, silly solution : replace every `<` with `[` and `>` with `]`, store in Your textbox, and after postback, in code behind, return them back to `<` and `>`.

Comment: @nelek why invent your own solution when you can just HTML encode it? Or since you're allowing arbitrary HTML anyway, you could turn off request validation for the page.